# Create Button filled to parent horizontally and vertically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i want to create a button which can filled the parent horizontally and vertically.
Below is the code :

```
          Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: getResultHeight(0.4),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 12),
              child: Card(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: new Text('data'),
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: new Text('data')),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: new Text('data'),
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: new Text('data')),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]))),
```

This is the result of above code :
[image: Above]

and below is the view that i want to achieve :
[image: Result to achieve]

I have tried to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in the `Row` but still can't achieve what i want.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it with `Row` and `Column` only then try this,

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 12),
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.orange,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

But you can easily achieve it with `GridView`,

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 12),
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5.0,
    color: Colors.orange,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Text('data'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Text('data'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Text('data'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Text('data'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i end up using Row and Column and added padding inside Expanded. I tried to use GridView but the view need to be scrolled down.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to wrap your `RaisedButton` widget inside a `SizedBox` widget with the specified `height` and `width` values and use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` for the `Column` and `Row` widgets.

```
Container(
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    //margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 12),
    child: Card(
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 182.5,
                  height: 138.5,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 182.5,
                  height: 138.5,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 182.5,
                  height: 138.5,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 182.5,
                  height: 138.5,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: new Text('data'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Flutter isn't my best language but if i remember properly you could try to wrap each button in an expanded widget? you might get an error but worth a shot.